# GKE cluster Restore for deleted backup paln

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a backup plan for a test cluster and created a manual backup of cluster. I have restored the cluster to another cluster when cluster is alive with restore plan. when I have to test for disaster scenario, I have deleted original cluster, the backup plan associated with cluster also got deleted but backups are present.
when i tried to create a new restore plan it says only alive cluster backup plans will be selected. I have a backup of cluster but i can not restore into another cluster.
Any other solution to restore cluster with GKE Backup-restore agent in GCP in above scenario where backups are present but backup plans are not there.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is?  And what are you using to backup your clusters?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a question here ? 
Are you able to run the already created restore pan corresponding to the backup plan for deleted cluster ?